# Why is a fatal error being generated when invoking a new class instance in Joomla?

Tags: php, joomla, fatal-error

One of our company web application's functions recently stopped working properly. The application was built with Joomla. The error log is generating this fatal error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'getXML' not found in /var/www/mycompanysite.com/html/display/listener.php on line 5
```

The code block in question here looks like this ($insert_sql is a dummy query for testing only, same fatal error without this query present):

```
<?php
include("config.php");// $myVar = 4 in this file, test #1
include("message.class.php"); //$myVar = 5 in this file, separate test #2
$xml = $_REQUEST['messagelist'];
$insert_sql = mysql_query("insert into messages (message, pid) values ('".$myVar."','999999');");
$retrieverobj = new getXML($xml);

    // etc.
```

The files config.php and message.class.php are both in the same folder as listener.php (I have changed both includes to reference the file's absolute path but same result), so the path should not be an issue. I have done two tests. In the first test (config.php), the value 4 appears in the `messages` table (in the message column) after the script runs, so the first include works for config.php it appears. In the second test, the value 5 does NOT appear after the script runs, (a null appears to be inserted), so the second include seems to be failing.

I am new to Joomla, so I thought it might have some class naming convention (since the class name is getXML and the file name is message.class.php). So I retried with this line in my second include statement:

```
include("getXML.class.php"); //also tried as include("getXML.php");
```

but the same fatal error resulted (and I also tried as require instead of include).

Here is the class in question (I should add that when I even delete the entire function, so that only `class getXML{}` is present as an empty class, **the fatal error is still present**):

```
class getXML{

function getXML($incomingMessage){

    global $keyword, $phonenumber, $carriercode, $messagebody;

    $messagelist_xml = simplexml_load_string(stripslashes($incomingMessage));

    $from = urldecode($messagelist_xml->{'message-list'}->message->from);

    $messagebody = urldecode($messagelist_xml->{'message-list'}->message->body);

    $keywordarray=explode(" ",$messagebody);

    $keyword = $keywordarray[0];

    if($_GET['keyword'] != ''){

        $keyword = $_GET['keyword'];

    }

    $phonenumber= substr($from,-10);

    $carriercode= strstr($from, '=');
    $carriercode= substr($carriercode,1,5);

    }
}
```

Any ideas on what is happening here? Why is the second include failing on this Joomla site?

Comment: show the code for `message.class.php` because `include("message.class.php");` should be correct, and it should be defined as `class getXML{}` but that sound like a function name

Comment: did you confirm that the include succeeded? e.g. change it to a `require`.

Comment: @MarcB, which include? The first one yes, because I added $myVar = 4; to the config.php file and this value was inserted into our database, the second include failed using the same procedure (that is, with $myVar = 5; only in message.class.php, 5 was not inserted into the database, an empty value was)

Comment: @meda, ok will edit my question to show the class

Comment: @TheOneandOnlyChemistryBlob: the getXML one. if it says the class doesn't exist, then confirm that the file that defines the class is being included.

Comment: @MarcB...that's what I mean...this class (getXML) is not being included because include("message.class.php"); appears to not include this file

Comment: @jeroen, this is legacy code that is a few years old...we don't develop with Joomla anymore, and as far as I can tell last update was almost 2 years ago

Comment: My hack solution will be to import the function getXML() into the file listener.php and just return the necessary values from the function (i.e., I'll substitute invoking the class with a direct function call in listener.php)

Comment: Are you working inside the CMS or is this a standalone application? YOu would not normally ever directly  include the config.php like that, instantiate the application object instead. Joomla has a lot of built in classes for handling things like getXML() you might want to just extend those.   ANyway it would help if you would explain a bit about what you are trying to do. Yes there are naming conventions for autoloading.

Comment: I know...the configuration.php file is elsewhere...I think the developer (no longer here, nothing documented) who built this needed another config-like file and just called it config.php

Comment: Welcome to my world! :)

Comment: lol ok so part of the issue is dealing with non Joomla code in a Joomla context. Is this being used as part of the CMS? And you are saying this code was working fine before and now it stopped?  DId you update the cms or change php versions or anything? This really looks like PHP 4 code in some ways and Joomla 1 or 1.5.

Comment: Also it seems weird that it would change, but check the file permissions and ownership.  PS this is in no way Joomla code unless it was possibly from Joomla 1.0.  Even then ... this just looks like PHP.

Comment: @Elin...just checked file perms....config.php and message.class.php same

Comment: What about ownership?

Comment: owner is apache...I used chown -R apache:apache /mypath to make sure ownership was correct...this helped for some file permission warnings on log files I was getting, but didn't help with the fatal error

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if you are allowed to use the same class name and function name:

```
class getXML{

function getXML($incomingMessage){
```

The bigger problem is you don't have a constructor that takes an argument

So try to change it to :

```
public function __construct($incomingMessage)
{
```

And also pick better names for a class.

Comment: I wasn't sure about having the same class and function name too, so I tried re-naming the function - same fatal error.

Comment: you need a constructor `function __construct` not a regular function

Comment: Thanks for your help. I added public function __construct($incomingMessage) {$this->message = $incomingMessage; } to the same class and changed this line $messagelist_xml = simplexml_load_string(stripslashes($incomingMessage)); to $messagelist_xml = simplexml_load_string(stripslashes($this->message)); same fatal error. I will implement my hack solution now (mentioned above).

Comment: IF the behavior that was formerly working suddenly changed it is unlikely to be due to lack of a constructor.